# Azure Arm template dependson with linked template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to use the [dependsOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-define-dependencies#dependson) element with resources in a linked template? Or other methods to force linked template resources to deploy before a resource in the main template?

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible - you need to set the dependsOn / dependency on the nested deployment resource itself, e.g.

```
"dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'myLinkedDeploymentName')]" ]
```

Comment: Hi @bmoore-msft, thanks for the answer, after some testing, I think there is a bug for dependsOn for linked template. The main template does not wait for the linked template to finish when using dependsOn.

Comment: Can you send me a repro?  Either here or feel free to email bmoore at microsoft...

Comment: Was this ever pursued?

Comment: TBH I don't remember...  If you're running into something similar take a look at: https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/ - if that doesn't help lmk.